# Using application context as queries' parent context

Tags: go

I am currently passing application/main context from `main.go` to `repository.go` so that I can use it as "parent" context to go with query context. Is this valid/idiomatic usage or not? Also, shall I ditch the idea and just use `context.Background()` as "parent" context to go with query context instead?

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "internal/user"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    repo := user.NewRepository(ctx, db)

    // HTTP server is running.
}
```

**internal/user/repository.go**

```golang
package user

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "time"
)

type Repository struct {
    *sql.DB
}

var appCTX context.Context

func NewRepository(ctx context.Context, db *sql.DB) Repository {
    appCTX = ctx

    return Repository{db}
}

func (r Repository) Insert(args ...interface{}) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(appCTX, 5 * time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    // Run query etc.
    res, err := r.ExecContext(ctx, `INSERT INTO .....`, args...)
}
```

Comment: What are you using the "main" context *for*?

Comment: Any operation depends on the main/parent/root context should be cancelled - due to a signal etc. For example, if this ctx is cancelled, all running queries should be cancelled or HTTP client calls etc.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic use of context is to pass it as the first function argument, and not store in structs. This is from the context doc:

> Do not store Contexts inside a struct type; instead, pass a Context explicitly to each function that needs it. The Context should be the first parameter, typically named ctx

So, even if you pass the main context down to your implementation, you should do that by passing the context to each operation.

Each self-contained operation (such as an HTTP request) should create a new context. If your main performs one such self-contained operation, you can pass the context down like this. However, if this is a server application, you should create a separate context for each request handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of everything you pointed out so far. However,  my questions is very specific to the usage of the very root application context which is created only once at boot. For example if I use Request context as query's parent context for each operation, it sometimes randomly errors with context timeout etc. If I use what I showed above (either one) all work fine. That's why I am trying to find out if it is perfectly fine what I am doing above or is it a blind work!

Comment: If request context times out or cancels, then you shouldn't be producing results for that request. That's the purpose of the context. If your purpose in using main context is to circumvent that situation, then you should use the request context, not main context. A main context could be useful if, for instance, you want to gracefully shutdown all running goroutines when program is about to terminate.